# Firebase Storage async image download random order

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm trying to download images from firebase storage to display in my collectionview cells, but the images keep appearing in random order in the cells. The cells each have a label that is retrieved from firebase storage (item1, item2 etc) which displays nicely in the correct cell every time. The images stored in firebase storage each have their storage url as a child to their respective item name in the firebase database.

I'm sucesfully able to retrieve each image url, and download all the images and display them in the cells correctly, it's just that they keep appearing in randomized order every time I open the app, so the image does not correspond with the item name label.

I realize i need to asyncronously download the images, so each image finishes loading in the correct cell before continuing to the next, but I'm having trouble doing so. Heres my code so far:

```
    func downloadImg(completion: @escaping (UIImage?) -> ()) {
    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("somePath")
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        for item in snapshot.children {
            let snap = item as! DataSnapshot
            let imageSnap = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: "img/storageUrl")
            if let url = imageSnap.value as? String {
            let someRef = self.storageRef.reference(forURL: url)
                someRef.getData(maxSize: 10 * 10024 * 10024) { data, error in
                    if let error = error {
                        print(error)
                    } else {
                        let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            completion(image)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then I call my function in the viewdidload:

```
    downloadImg { (completion) in
            self.itemPicArray.append(completion!)
            self.collectionView?.reloadData()
        }
```

Finally i set my cell imageview to `itemPicArray[indexPath.row]`

Like I said, this works perfectly except the fact that the images keep showing up randomly. Help very much appreciated!

Comment: Take a look at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchgroup . Makes sure the image has been downloaded before downloading the next image; whereas your current thinking just downloads it all at the same time & will give back mixed results.

Comment: I tried this, creating a DispatchGroup instance and using .enter and .leave but this seemingly did nothing. Should I use .wait instead? Or something else?

Comment: I assume you also used .notify on your DispatchGroup? I have experienced difficulties using DispatchGroup when making an async call within the loop. Where did you .leave() your for-in-loop?

Comment: I did not, will try that next. I used .enter right at the start of the function and .leave right after the else statement in someRef.getData. I'm quite inexperienced with async programming so I'm not really sure what to put where, and what to include.

Comment: Forgive this poor editing style; I’m on a cell. I have not tried your code. But what I had in mind was this: group.enter() placed at top of loop; group.leave() placed before the closing bracket of someRef.getData(); group.notify() placed after closing bracket of loop. I guess you would then need to send back your images as [UIImage] (rather than UIImage) and change your call accordingly, something like self.itemPicArray = completion.

Comment: Posted my suggestion as an answer. Worth looking into maybe...?

Answer (score 2):

Using a model could be a good idea.

```
struct Image {
    var imageName: String
    var image: UIImage
}
```

This way, no matter the order, the item name (image name) and the image will be paired.

Perhaps a better solution now is to configure method downloadImg so that it takes the imageName as a parameter. Then you can call the correct node to get the corresponding storageURL.

```
func downloadImg(imageName: String, completion: @escaping (Image?) -> ()) {

    // Use the parameter to create your database reference    
    let ref = Database.database().reference().child(imageName)
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        for item in snapshot.children {

            let snap = item as! DataSnapshot
            let imageSnap = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: "img/storageUrl")
            if let url = imageSnap.value as? String {
                let someRef = self.storageRef.reference(forURL: url)
                someRef.getData(maxSize: 10 * 10024 * 10024) { data, error in
                    if let error = error {
                        print(error)
                        return
                    } 

                    if let image = UIImage(data: data) {
                        // Create a variable of type Image (your custom model)
                        let imageWithName = Image(imageName: imageName, image: image)
                        completion(imageWithName)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Calling and handling could be done like so:

```
// Create a variable to hold your item name/image-pairs
var imagesWithNames = [Image]()

let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

// Iterate over your array of item names
for item in itemArray {

    dispatchGroup.enter()

    downloadImg(item) { (imageWithName) in
        self.imagesWithNames.append(imageWithName)
        dispatchGroup.leave()
    }
}

dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) { {
    self.collectionView?.reloadData()
}
```

And to populate the collectionView you can go:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! YourCustomCell

    // Get the pair at the given index
    let imageWithName = self.imagesWithNames[indexPath.row]

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // Set image and item label (example below)
        self.yourImageView.image = imageWithName.image
        self.yourItemLabel.text = imageWithName.imageName
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried doing exactly as you said in my code, but unfortunately I have the exact same problem as before. I've tried many different ways of doing this and looked at lots of other posts on the forum but I still can't seem to make it work. So frustrating! :(

Comment: Ah, too bad!! How do you populate your collection view? More specifically, where and how do you ”pair” the name with the image?

Comment: For the name I retrieve all item names from fb db and put it into an array. Then I use itemArray[indexPath.row] to correctly display the name in each cell. 

In the db each "itemName" node has a child "img" which has a child with key "storageUrl" and the url is the key. So I'm trying to do the same thing with images as with item names - create an array and use indexPath.row to populate the cell.

The only "pairing" between image and item name is that the image url is inside the correct item name in the DB - maybe this is where the problem lies? Perhaps i need to pair the two differently?

Comment: Happened to wipe out my previous answer with a new one.

Comment: @codeski in case you're still struggling I edited my answer

Comment: The code makes sense, storing images with names. I'm able to replicate it without errors, but unfortunately it's still not working. The cells now show up with no images instead :/ Really don't understand what I'm doing wrong, damn.

Comment: Can you try and debug by printing your [Image] (or whatever you ended up calling your custom object) to the console, right before reloading the collectionView for example. This way me may be able to locate where we go wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately now, I tried doing debugprint() on the custom object, as well as printing in the console after the crash but it just says that the [Image] array is empty. I tried hard coding the url's and everything. I'm able to display the hard coded images directly into a cell, but turning the download images into an array of [Image] does not seem to work for me for some reason :/ I'm looking to hire an iOS tutor online to help me with the problem, will update here whenever I get the answer! Thanks so much for your help though Dan, need more people like you on here!

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that everytime an image comes in, you reload the entire collection view. Depending on the sizes of the images and the state of the network, the images will come in in a different order almost every time.

Consider downloading all of the images first and then reloading the collection view once. If there are a lot of images, consider paginating your results. You can enumerate the loop and sort the data source array by this original order. I've added a custom data object to help with that.

```
class CustomObject {

    var image: UIImage?
    let n: Int

    init(image: UIImage?, n: Int) {
        self.image = image
        self.n = n
    }

}

let dispatch = DispatchGroup()

for (n, item) in snapshot.children.enumerated() {

    let object = CustomObject(image: nil, n: n) // init custom object with n (image is still nil)
    dispatch.enter() // enter dispatch

    someRef.getData(maxSize: 10 * 10024 * 10024) { data, error in // download image
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
        } else {
            let image = UIImage(data: data!)
            object.image = image // inject custom object with image
            itemPicArray.append(object) // append to array
        }
        dispatch.leave() // leave dispatch
    }

}

dispatch.notify(queue: .global()) { // dispatch completion

    itemPicArray.sort { $0.n < $1.n } // sort by n (original download order)
    collectionView.reloadData() // reload collection view

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I have some problems stil - where should I call collectionview.reloaddata so it is only called once? Also I tried your code but at the line 'itemPicArray.append(object)' it gives the error "Cannot convert value of type 'CollectionViewCell.CustomObject' to expected argument type 'UIImage'". Am I supposed to use a dictionary for storing the images instead?

Comment: You need to update your array to be of type `CustomObject` (or whatever the custom object ultimately is). And the collection view is reloaded in the dispatch notify function (the last line in my code). That function is called once after all of the dispatch entering and leaving (the calls to download and the actual image downloads) have finished.

Comment: You will still need your array of strings right? Keep your itemPicArray - which I assume is of type [String]() - and create new array of type CustomObject.

Comment: Great, I've implemented your code and It's error free, but how can I display the images which are stored in a CustomObject array in my collectionview cells? Also I understand you put the downloaded image as the CustomObjects image property, but what about the n property? Do we not need to give each picture an int n as well?

Comment: I'm assuming cell.cellImg.image = itemPicArray[indexPath.row].image would be the correct way of displaying the image? I did so, and there are no errors, but the no images in the cells either. My array looks like this: var itemPicArray = [CustomObject]()

Comment: Post your code somewhere so I can see what you’ve done

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is having issues with this in the future, use -bsod answer and create a custom object. Also create a variable var counter: Int = 0. Here's how my code looks like Swift 5.X and it works perfectly.

```
class CustomObject {

var image: UIImage?
let n: Int

init(image: UIImage?, n: Int) {
    self.image = image
    self.n = n
}
```

}

```
func reloadStuff() {
    dispatch.notify(queue: .main) {
        self.imageArrayCells.sort { $0.n < $1.n }
        self.contentViewProfile.collectionView.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
        self.contentViewProfile.collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}

for i in 0 ..< self.imageArrayInfo.count {

let object = CustomObject(image: nil, n: i)
let urlString = self.imageArrayInfo[i]
print(object.n)

let url = URL(string: urlString)
self.dispatch.enter()
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
    self.dispatch.enter()
    guard let data = data, error == nil else {
        return
    }
    guard let image = UIImage(data: data) else {
        return
    }
    object.image = image
    self.imageArrayCells.append(object)
    self.dispatch.leave()
    self.counter += 1
    if self.counter == self.imageArrayInfo.count {
        for i in 0 ..< self.imageArrayInfo.count {
            self.dispatch.leave()
        }
        self.counter = 0
    }
}
task.resume()
```

}

```
self.reloadStuff()
```

Here's what I'm calling in collectionView(cellForItemAt:_)

```
cell.imageInProfileCollection.image = imageArrayCells[indexPath.row].image
```